# Criando Responsividades com tipos de Densidades

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu tenho algumas curiosidades enorme no seguinte quesito:

- Para cada tipo de **density** criamos **tipos de pastas**, como por exemplo:

> **drawable-xxhdpi** - [**Imagens**]
>
> **layout-xxhdpi** - [**XML**]
>
> **values-xxhdpi** - [**Colors, Styles, Strings, Dimens**]

- **PERGUNTAS**:

> **1)** Temos o dimens para poder colocar o tamanho dos textos entre outros para utilizar nas telas, porém isto é realmente útil? Pois eu
> poderia colocar dentro do XML de cada tipo de tela, esse tamanho não
> irá ser reutilizável em outra tela então não estarei repetindo código.
> O Colors, String e Style eu até entendo, mas o dimens não.
>
> **2)** Além dos tipos de density (420DPI,560DPI,HDPI,XHPDI..), em cada tipo de desnity tempos um ou mais sizes, como por exemplo: O HDPI tem 2 tipos de sizes: Normal e Small, porém também existem 2 tipos de resolutions:480x 800 e 480x854. Como cria responsividade para esta questão?

Comment: Se houver algo que as respostas à pergunta indicada no fechamento não esclareçam, edite a sua pergunta com essa dúvida especifica.

Comment: @ramaral, ela não esclarece minha pergunta. 1) 3), 4) e 5). Ele se posiciona de um modo genérico. O que devo fazer para minha perguntar ar sem ser duplicata e ser respondida?

Comment: A sua pergunta também é genérica, logo só pode ser respondida de forma genérica.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta está um pouco ampla também(meu voto foi esse, na verdade).

Comment: @ramaral, irei editar minha pergunta e vocês confiram.

Comment: @diegofm, editei minha pergunta.

Comment: @ramaral, editei minha pergunta.

Comment: Apesar da edição a pergunta continua a ser duplicata. Para responder a essas duas situações teria de repetir as coisas ditas lá. Você tem que perceber os conceitos lá descritos e entender as várias abordagens a seguir. Algumas vezes é necessário aplicar mais de uma para obter o resultado pretendido.

Comment: @ramaral, por exemplo, como eu disse acima na pergunta 2). Eu teria que criar duas pastas diferentes para o HDPI? Se sim com quais nomes eu coloco ela?

Comment: Eventualmente não. A diferença de tamanho é tão pequena que não vejo necessidade. Isso é respondido no tópico *"Layouts responsivos(adaptáveis)"* da resposta à pergunta indicada no fechamento.